# Parallax RFID and Johnny-Five

Tags: node.js, arduino, johnny-five

I have a parallax RFID reader and I am confused on where to start when using johnny-five with it.  I am trying to use this as guidance - http://www.gumbolabs.org/2009/10/17/parallax-rfid-reader-arduino/ - but obviously that does not use johnny-five.

I don't know if I should be starting with a johnny-five object to read the data and interact with the sensor, or if I should skip that and be using `serialport` directly.  If I use `serialport` how exactly do I do that?

https://github.com/RyanHirsch/j5-rfid

Output:

```
1381834286406 Board Connecting... 
1381834286421 Serial Found possible serial port /dev/cu.usbmodemfa141
1381834286422 Board -> Serialport connected /dev/cu.usbmodemfa141
open
err undefined
results 3
```

Code:

```
var sp = new SerialPort("/dev/cu.usbmodemfa141", {
  parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\r") ,
  baudrate: 2400
}, false);

sp.open(function () {
  console.log('open');
  sp.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('data received: ' + data);
  });
  sp.write("ls\n", function(err, results) {
    console.log('err ' + err);
    console.log('results ' + results);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Johnny five is Node.js for robots but on your computer. The javascript code is executed on your computer. On the Arduino, you need to upload `StandarFirmata` [as explained on their github page](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five#setup-and-assemble-arduino).

The code from the Arduino <--> RFID tutorial you gave us if for Arduino only. If you want to use it with johnny five, you need to implement the code by your self or look for someone who did that for you on github. If you're having this problem, chances are someone else also had it and might have found an answer.

With `node serialport`, you'll be able to read the `Serial.print()` outputs of the Arduino. You can output `json` and parse it with javascript on your computer using `serialport`.

Hope it helps !

If you need more help, feel free to ask! :)

**EDIT 1:**

So if I understand it correctly: you have the RFID reader connected to the Arduino. The Arduino is connected to a computer. You want to read the RFID and send the information to the computer. The computer must be running a server and must be able to get the data from the USB port. All people connected to the server from the iPad should see the information in realtime. Is that correct?

If so, you need a node server, `node-serialport` to get the data from the USB and a web app such as express.js to show the data to your clients. The best way to do that would be to format your data as json so that it could be easily parsable on the server.

**EDIT 2:**
Okay! So here you can find two great tutorials by Tom Igoe on how to use Arduino and Node.js.

- [Arduino Serial to Browser](http://www.tigoe.com/pcomp/code/arduinowiring/1096/): Here you'll learn the basics of `node-serialport`and how to use it with your Arduino.
- [Serial to Browser using node.js](http://www.tigoe.com/pcomp/code/arduinowiring/1109/) : Here you'll learn how to `JSON`ize your Arduino data so that they can be easily accessible through your `web app` and `websocket`. He uses an accelerometer for his data, but I guess you can directly use your RFID data.

I'm sure that you'll have many more questions after this but it will be a good start!

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: When using `serialport` should that still be nested in a j5.Board `on.ready()`? What's the path to the serial port if j5 is being used (does j5 even impact it?)

Comment: not necessarily. It really depends on what you want to do. Question: why do you want to send your RFID data to your computer in the first place? Can't it work on it's own? What's the purpose of the whole project? That may seem unrelated but it really helpful to imagine and come out with and idea and/or a solution.
`serialport` can be used on it's own (sort of).

Comment: The goal is to have the board read the RFID, then those results are pushed to all clients via web sockets. The scenario is that I am planning on using this in an elementary classroom where the students have iPads and there is a projector at the front of the room.

Comment: Do you have any example of how do do that? Any sample code, examples, etc. I have updated my code but still not getting any progress.

Comment: @RyanHirsch Hey Ryan! Sorry for the delay! I updated my answer with great links and tutorial. It should answer your questions and put you on the right track :)

Answer (score 2):

The Firmata protocol (that which Johnny-Five uses to communicate with an Arduino) does not support SoftwareSerial or relinquishing the RX/TX lines of the board. That means that Johnny-Five *cannot* support this device.

Edit: Firmata protocol recently added support for hardware and software serial, which means RFID component support will likely soon be added